# How to validate a text field so it can only contain a four digit number

Tags: javascript

I've managed to validate my field so it is always four digits, but i need to validate so that it is always a number. I tried adding this block of code but it doesn't work properly.

```
if (!(document.ExamEntry.cand.value.match(numbers))) {
    msg += "Only use numeric characters \n";
    document.ExamEntry.cand.focus();
    document.getElementById('cand').style.color = "red";
    result = false;
}
```

This will allow four digit combinations like 9a9a or !2#3 etc.
I added the "numbers" variable like this;

```
var numbers = /[0-9]/;
```

What is a better way of doing this validation?

Comment: The regular expression is wrong. "Four digits and nothing else" is `/^[0-9]{4}$/`. What you have now is "at least one digit anywhere in the input".

Comment: This is GCSE assessed work, going towards a formal qualification. No help should have been asked for in this way. I don't know the exact rule around the qualification, but I suspect this is against them.

Comment: EDIT: Sorry, I just remembered you can ask IT sources for help. It's fine (I think.).

Answer (score 6):

Let's say you get your value here

```
var val = document.ExamEntry.cand.value;
```

Then if you want it to be something with 4 digits inside, just do this

```
var itIsNumber = /^\d{4}$/.test(val); // true if it is what you want
```

if you want it to be something with 1 to 4 digits inside, just do this

```
var itIsNumber = /^\d{1,4}$/.test(val); // true if it is what you want
```

more examples and details here --> [Regular Expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions)

Answer (score 3):

`/^[0-9]{4}$/` for four numbers

`/^[0-9]*$/` for any amount of numbers

`/^[0-9]+$/` for at least one number